# windows command not responding to ruby - trying to call a macro with a .mac file extension

Tags: ruby, cmd, windows-7

I have a macro file that i can run in the cmd line in windows by simply navigating to the directory and typing `profit.mac` in the cmd line

however, when i go to call it in a ruby script i keep getting errors

I have tried `system()`, `exec()`, ``` `` ```, and `%x()` and i havent been able to get it to work

are there any other options I have to call my macro file?

i get the same error on 3/4 of them

(backticks), `profit.mac` = (Errno::ENOEXEC)
`exec('profit.mac')` = (Errno::ENOEXEC)
`%x('profit.mac')` = (Errno::ENOEXEC)
`system('profit.mac')` = nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your `.mac` macros files executables or need to be interpreted by another program?

I guess those macros files have to be interpreted by another "macros executor" program. You would need to prepend that in your command execution.

```
exec('macrosInterpreter.exe /path/to/profit.mac')
```

It is like running a ruby script. Assume you want to run a `test.rb` file. You can't do `exec('test.rb')`, you would have to do `exec('ruby test.rb')`.

Comment: nailed it, had to audit my task manager to find what launches when i run it but it worked :)